# Getting error on build server The "GetDependsOnNETStandard" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a project on my development machine it builds fine but on build server its gives following error. Can anybody tell me what can be the problem?

> 2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z (ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades
>   target) ->  2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018: The "GetDependsOnNETStandard" task failed unexpectedly.
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x8013110B): No .CLB data in the memory or stream. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8013110B)
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GetDependsOnNETStandard.IMetaDataDispenser.OpenScope(String
>   szScope, UInt32 dwOpenFlags, Guid& riid)
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GetDependsOnNETStandard.GetFileDependsOnNETStandard(String
>   filePath)
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GetDependsOnNETStandard.AnyReferenceDependsOnNETStandard()
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5249293Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GetDependsOnNETStandard.ExecuteCore()
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5405544Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5405544Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5405544Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(48,5):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>   [e:\vs\a_w\332\s\Net\CompiledScriptSupport\PrecompiledService\LoadersReportsManagementService\LoadersReportsManagementService.csproj]
>   2017-11-08T20:38:30.5405544Z  2017-11-08T20:38:30.5405544Z     0
>   Warning(s) 2017-11-08T20:38:30.5405544Z     1 Error(s)

Comment: This was extensiblity project and was giving error with x64. I changed to x86 it builds fine.